# How to get response from server in Android,It is crashing

Tags: android

I am sending GPS coordinates to server, but i need response from server to client,It is crashing here when i try to getresponse i am not getting how to do this,

Here is my AsyncTask class

```
 private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://182.18.144.140:80");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LAT", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LON", lng));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
            }           

            return null;
        }
            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updated Server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  etResponse.setText(result);
       }
    }
```

It is my logcat

```
 01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): Process: com.example.server4, PID: 1290
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at com.example.server4.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:199)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at com.example.server4.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-24 05:44:41.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: where is your variable response in all this?

Comment: @DarkoRodic When i tried use response using String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) my app is crashing

Comment: well, that should not happen, maybe you should post your logs and some code if needed

Answer (score 0):

well try maybe to add this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

and then:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You are trying to display toast in non-ui thread that's why this error apear.

If you want to display toast in doInBackground method then you have to write your Toast logic inside UI thread

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://182.18.144.140:80");
            String responseBody="";

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LAT", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LON", lng));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
                responseBody = e.getMessage();
            }           

            return responseBody;
        }
            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updated Server!"+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  etResponse.setText(result);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, it is not crashing now, but it is not showing response from server

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
try {
    httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By this

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
if (response != null) {
    EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
```

And Utils

```
public static String toString(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```